# HTML string, get the first href

Tags: c#, html, ssis

I'm writing a C# script in SSIS-2016, Using Visual Studio-2015.

Requirement: Download the HTML from the URL and get the earliest Date (href) and set this date as a variable.

I've got this so far:

```
public void Main()
{
    string username = Dts.Variables["$Package::user"].Value.ToString();
    string password = Dts.Variables["$Package::pwd"].Value.ToString();
    string URL = Dts.Variables["$Package:URL"].Value.ToString();

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    var webResponse = request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

So the HTML will look like this:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Index of /file-download/</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
    <h1>Index of /file-download/</h1><hr><pre><a href="../">../</a>
    <a href="20170826/">20170826/</a>                                          27-Aug-2017 00:05                   -
    <a href="20170827/">20170827/</a>                                          28-Aug-2017 00:05                   -
    <a href="20170828/">20170828/</a>                                          29-Aug-2017 00:05                   -
    <a href="ProductDefinitions/">ProductDefinitions/</a>                                26-Aug-2017 16:58                   -
    <a href="file-download-automation.readme.txt">file-download-automation.readme.txt</a>                12-Aug-2017 01:56                1061
    </pre><hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I need to do is somehow get the Earliest Dated `href` from the string `responseFromServer`, I can then pass this to a `DTS.Variable`.

I've seen loads of regex answers but I cannot get it to work for me.

If anyone could help I would be really appreciative.

Comment: Do you have any control over the format of the html page that is being retrieve? for example can you change the markup and add a class to all the anchor tags that have dates?

Comment: No I do not have control over the format of the HTML its a 3rd party website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML Agility pack to parse the html and extract the values (https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)

Given your structure, this is how I managed to get the info from the html.

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(rawHtml);
var first = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
    .Where(_ => _.Name == "a")
    .OfType<HtmlNode>()
    .Select(_ => _.Attributes["href"])
    .Select(_ => 
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime.TryParseExact(_.Value, "yyyyMMdd/", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out var result);
            return (DateTime?)result;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    })
    .Where(_=> _.HasValue)
    .OrderByDescending(_ => _.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I cannot download this: Install-Package : Project 'Default' is not found.At line:1 char:1 Nu-Get issue on VS2015, ive tried to use this but failing to get it installed https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1215

Comment: @JayBay2279 That is weird I just installed it and it worked perfectly ..

Comment: @Vanna, if your document conforms to XML, yes, but that might not be the case. Html Agility pack does dot use System.Xml. I have seen the code, it has a custom parser.

Comment: @Vanna Html Agility Pack is way more robust and capable of handling HTML then using the built in System.Xml.  A lot of development time has gone into that library, are you suggesting its no better than using System.Xml?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir What version of VS are you using?

Comment: @Vanna But since he does not have control over the original site, it would be better to use a HTML parser to make sure he doesn't get bitten by minor changes to HTML that might make the HTML invalid as XML

Comment: @Vanna what does XML have to do with anything?  You do know that HTML != XML right?

Comment: Im using SSIS, Business inteligence project/Solutions in VS2015 and from a quick test, I cannot apply the AgilityPack to a SSIS solution, I can however add it in using the command from your link @TitianCernicova-Dragomir when using a Win Forms Application. So Agility Pack isnt an answer for this Question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this would be better within the boundaries of SSIS and your request since this is a sample that includes regex.

testInput is the sample data you provided

```
var rx = new Regex(@"<a href="".*?"">(?<date>\d{8})/</a>\s+\d{2}-.{3}-\d{4}\s(?<hh>\d{2}):(?<mm>\d{2})");
var oldest = rx.Matches(testInput).Cast<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>().
            Where(match => match.Success).
            Select(g =>
            {
                decimal result;
                decimal.TryParse(g.Groups["date"].Value + g.Groups["hh"].Value + g.Groups["mm"].Value, out result);
                return result;
            }
        ).Except(new[] { default(decimal) }).OrderBy(dt => dt).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thank you for your help, what Namespaces do I need for this to work? using System.Text.RegularExpressions? I only ask because im getting errors on Cast<Match>

Comment: Updated to include namespaces and parse exact (DateTime). - this is just a very quick & dirty sample - you should consider changing this to work as a stream processor.

Comment: thanks for your help so far, very much appreciated, could you help a little more and  tweak the regex so that it takes the Dateformat "yyyymmdd" as its that folder structure i need, I'm terrible at Regex.

Comment: It will sort as decimal you can parse the oldest to a datetime.